# How to mapping list of points with list coordinates by keyname?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, coordinates

Please help me, I have 2 list:
List of coordinates:

```
coordinateArr= [[A,190,340],[B,270,580],[C,395,140]]
```

List of Rountines:

```
path=[A,B,C,A,B]
```

How to map list path with coordinateArr, the result like this:

```
result=[[190,340],[270,580],[395,140],[190,340],[270,580]]
```

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
coordinateArr= [['A',190,340],['B',270,580],['C',395,140]]
path=['A','B','C','A','B']

[a[1:] for p in path for a in coordinateArr if p==a[0]]
```

Output:

```
[[190, 340], [270, 580], [395, 140], [190, 340], [270, 580]]
```

This is more or less the same like:

```
output = []

for p in path:
   for a in coordinateArr:    
      if p == a[0]:
         output.append(a[1:])
```

Comment: Thank you!!! @nauer but can you please explain clearly this syntax: [a[1:] for p in path for a in coordinateArr if p==a[0]]  :(

Answer (score 1):

Make `coordinateArr` as `dict`:

```
coordinateArr= [['A',190,340],['B',270,580],['C',395,140]]
path=['A','B','C','A','B']

d = {i[0]:i[1:] for i in coordinateArr}

[d.get(p) for p in path]
```

Output:

```
[[190, 340], [270, 580], [395, 140], [190, 340], [270, 580]]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! But can you please explain what is the syntax i[0]:i[1:] ? @Chris